# Motherboard and video card compatibility?

Tags: motherboard

I'm in the middle of testing an EVGA 680i LT SLI motherboard with the following:

- Intel Pentium 4 520J 2.8 GHz
- Qimonda 1GB DDR2-800 SDRAM
- LITE-ON IDE DVD-ROM drive
- HIS Radeon HD4350 256MB DDR2
- OCZ ModXStream 500W supply

I have connected the main 24-pin, EPS 8-pin and molex connectors on the motherboard. The machine powers up as usual, but there are no POST beeps, no video and no response from the DVD drive. The processor should be supported, I'm only using one working module of RAM, I've reset CMOS, I've reseated the CPU, I've tried a dual-channel configuration of RAM, and I've tried running with and without the molex power connector on the motherboard.

Therefore, can I assume that this motherboard is no longer in working condition?

Comment: Do you have a case speaker connected to the motherboard so that you would be able to hear the beeps if they were happening?

Comment: What about all the fan cables?

Comment: @typoknig: There aren't any headers that allow for an internal speakers, so I'm guessing that it's integrated or something.

Comment: @Aki: There are fans on the motherboard, for the CPU and the PSU itself. They're all running properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If when you turn the computer on, the case fans don't turn on and you cannot eject the DVD drive (and the DVD is connected to power), then the power supply is bad.  Make sure it is seated properly into the motherboard (push it down hard).  Make sure the switch on the back of your computer is on (switched to "1").  Try swapping out the power supply first.  You might be able to spot a kaput PSU by looking for burnt pins or testing it with a multimeter.  If you have a multimeter, you do this by connecting the power supply to a power outlet and turn on.  Set the multimeter to test for DC Volts and connect the black lead to black wire pinout and the other lead on your multimeter (usually red) to a yellow wire pinout.  The reading on your multimeter should be 12V.  Connecting black to black and the red lead to a red wire pinout should give you a reading of 5V.

If fans are in fact turning on, the processor could be bad, as the motherboard needs a working processor installed in order to initiate POST beep codes.  There are ways of testing CPUs with a multimeter, but if you look at it and don't see any burn markings on the die or any of the pins, chances are it is ok.

The next component would be the case speaker.  It is the internal speaker that will alert you if RAM, video card, or keyboard is missing or bad.  There are pins on the motherboard that the speaker connects to.  The speaker could be bad or it isn't connected properly.  You can buy a replacement.  [http://amazon.com/o/asin/B002W4M0DW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002W4M0DW)

The RAM, video card, and DVD-ROM player are not important in testing.  One or all could be bad, but typically you would get POST error codes that would alert you to this.  Lookup the POST error codes for your motherboard from the manufacturer's website.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fans are working. I was actually thinking about the CPU possibility. I bought the processor off eBay for ~$10, so I might be able to test with another. As I stated as a comment in the other answer, there's no place to attach an internal speaker, so I'm guessing there's an internal speaker integrated on the motherboard. The video card is required for testing as there is no onboard.

Comment: The video card is NOT required for testing.  Neither is the RAM.  If the computer reaches POST, then it will require a video card and RAM to proceed with the boot process further... HOWEVER, it appears (http://www.evga.com/support/manuals/files/122-CK-NF67.pdf) your motherboard *doesn't have a speaker* ... integrated or not.  This would be fine, but it has no visual indication of failure either (LEDs).  This is incredibly short-sighted and makes troubleshooting near impossible.  At this point, all you can do is swap known working components with another system until you find what ails your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you have replaced/reseated every component, minus the motherboard itself, you can safely assume that this motherboard has kicked proverbial the bucket.

Comment: This is generically good advice, but I would just state that you should usually try outside the case - I've seen standoffs short out a board before!

Comment: This is also true, I have seen case screws somehow get wedged behind motherboards

Comment: The motherboard has built-in washers to prevent that. I don't believe the board is shorted since the power supply is consistently feeding power to the motherboard. However, the CPU, GPU and RAM don't get warm. If anything, the CPU may be getting slightly warm without a cooler on... never hot.